How to set an Image as a Full Screen using Splash Screen API in Android
I have a Splash Activity in which there is an Image which covers the whole screen of device. Now I am migrating to Splash Screen API so how can I modify my handling to show that same Image on full screen, because currently I am only getting an option to set an Icon which is placed at center of screen.
I tried with setting my image in windowBackground, also tried with windowIsTranslucent, tried diving the Image into 2 parts, placing one using windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon and other using windowSplashScreenBrandingImage but I am not able place the second image correctly, it is getting distorted, I tried changing the image size also. Please anyone help me with this.
Thanks

You may wish to talk to your graphic designers about adapting their splash screen to match Google's requirements. AFAIK, the only way to have "an Image which covers the whole screen of device" will be to have two splash screens: the system-supplied one, followed by your full-screen one.

To achieve this, you need to create a custom screen according to your requirements and also develop a splash screen API with an icon in the center of the screen. This is necessary because Android 12 and later versions have this functionality by default. For more information, please refer to the official documentation here.
